# How does one update complex options?

Tags: plugin-development, options

I'm using Tom McFarlin's WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate along with [JoeSz's Tutorial](https://github.com/JoeSz/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate-Tutorial).

I'm loading in a complex options item using

```php
$options = get_option($this->plugin_name);
```

This works fine for the load and for accessing the items. What I don't understand as yet is how to update the modified options back into the db.

For example, if I update the `$options` blob with

```php
$options['stamp1'] = (isset($input['stamp1']) && !empty($input['stamp1'])) ? esc_attr($input['stamp1']) : (new DateTime('NOW'))->format('c');
$options['stamp2'] = (isset($input['stamp2']) && !empty($input['stamp2'])) ? esc_attr($input['stamp2']) : (new DateTime('NOW'))->format('c');
$options['stamp3'] = (isset($input['stamp3']) && !empty($input['stamp3'])) ? esc_attr($input['stamp3']) : (new DateTime('NOW'))->format('c');
$options['stamp4'] = (isset($input['stamp4']) && !empty($input['stamp4'])) ? esc_attr($input['stamp4']) : (new DateTime('NOW'))->format('c');
```

the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) for update_option makes it's obvious that

```
update_option($this->plugin_name );
```

isn't going to work.

There is a `register_setting` in my `class-...-public.php` but it's not particularly obvious (to me anyway) how this gets called and whether it's actually updating the options in the db.

Clues?

Answer (score 0):

Having figured it out I'm a bit embarrassed. Nevertheless,

```
        update_option($this->plugin_name, $options);
```